# How to differentiate and simplify this expression to match the solution?

Tags: calculus

I'm having difficulty trying to differentiate and simplify this expression to match the solution. Guidance towards the proper steps would be very helpful!

I apologize for not knowing how to use MathJax so here's a photo:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=2x+(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^3$.  Then we have $y=u^5$, so $y^\prime=5uu^\prime$.

Let $v=x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}$.  Then $v^\prime=2x+\frac{2}{x^3}$.

Putting this all together in the unsimplified form, we have

$y^\prime=5\left[2x+(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^3\right]\left[2+3(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^2(2x+\frac{2}{x^3}\right]$.

Note that we can factor a $2$ out of $u^\prime$ without much trouble.  So,

$y^\prime=10\left[2x+(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^3\right]^4\left[1+3(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^2(x+\frac{1}{x^3})\right]$.

If you can see that $(x+\frac{1}{x^3})=\frac{1}{x^3}(x^4+1)$, then you have basically seen the simplification.  Multiply the $u^\prime$ by $\frac{x^3}{x^3}$, and you get

$y^\prime=\frac{10}{x^3}\left[2x+(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^3\right]^4\left[x^3+3(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^2(x^4+1)\right]$.